# Adding a header to a theme

Tags: elementor

I'm building a theme demo with Elementor, but I can't get the (Elementor) header to show up. It's in the published templates. But I have to  open the header template and activate it.

In the [developers documentation](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/themes/registering-locations/) I found this:

```
    $elementor_theme_manager->register_location( 'header' );
    $elementor_theme_manager->register_location( 'footer' );
}
add_action( 'elementor/theme/register_locations', 'theme_prefix_register_elementor_locations' );
```

I have added this to my theme, but that doesn't work. The header is named 'header'. What am I doing wrong here?